# Facebook like button https issue: protocol mismatch from http and https

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm running an error very similar with this one: [Facebook Login API HTTPS Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888095/facebook-login-api-https-issue).

I have a website use facebook authentication, the Facebook login is no problem. But the Facebook like-button get troubled when been clicked (test fail on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, in OSX), the error message is:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a 
frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame requesting 
access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol
of "http". Protocols must match.
```

I've searched all over and find no solutions.

It seems like that when the like-button is clicked, it pop out a frame from https://facebook.com callback and trying to request http://static.ak.facebook.com thus cause protocol mismatch?!

Here's what I put right after `<body>` tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'appid',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//mydomain/channel.html',        // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and the channel file at `http://mydomain/channel`

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js"></script>
```

and here's how I use the like-button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href=url data-send="true" data-width="450"
data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Really needs help, please!

Comment: have you tried to add the protocol to the script src?

Comment: if you are using // instead of http or https it suppose to trigger request with the protocol match the browser protocol, make sure all your code urls are starting with just // e.g src="//yoursite.com"

Comment: Have you tried iframe version of like button ?

Comment: Are you seeing any other problems or just a message in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first script tag you can tell Facebook explicitly to use HTTPS...

Add the line:

```
FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");
```

Add it before the FB.init function call, just below or in place of the comment:

```
// init the FB JS SDK
```

This will ensure that Facebook's servers load any required libraries their end over https.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You must be the holy savior. This problem still exists, but thanks to you it has gone away !

Comment: Ha - happy to help, sad to hear this is still an issue nearly 2 years later. Glad I don't do much FB dev any more!

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the js code on Facebook there are multiple urls containing hard coded strings for

```
http://static .../rsrc.php
```

it's possible those are the files triggering the error.

This may be something Facebook needs to update.

On a side note, it may be possible to download that js file from Facebook and store it on your server and remove the hard coded http string. I would test this further but I am on my phone at the moment.